# I want to hide search bar from google place picker api

Tags: android

[Click to this to view Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUyq4.jpg) I'm Using Google Place Picker Api and now i want to hide upper search bar from place picker is there any way to do .

i search a lot on internet but not find any solution.

```
btn_map.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {

                PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
                intentBuilder.setLatLngBounds(BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW);
                Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(MainActivity.this);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }
        }
    });

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST
            && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        final Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(this, data);
        final CharSequence name = place.getName();
        final CharSequence address = place.getAddress();
        String attributions = (String) place.getAttributions();
        if (attributions == null) {
            attributions = "";
        }

    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode, data);
    }
}
```